# What kind of RAM should i buy for my laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, memory

I have a HP Pavilion dv6-7000-sy laptop. It's about 5-6 years old now. It has a nvidia geforce 630m 2GB grpahics card. Laptop itself has 6GB ram installed, but with some investication it seems that 2gb of ram is reserved for the graphics card. It has a 4gb and 2gb ram installed. It has gotten very slow on booting and overall usage, it seems that its running out of ram, as in even when idel its using ~50% of the ram it has. I want to upgrade to larger rams, as it might help the situaton, but after seeing the setup, can i even upgrade both of the rams, or can i upgrade only 1 of the rams.

Comment: Slow on boot is probably the hard drive and not the ram. Graphics use VRAM not RAM. Even if that is the case and your system is actually using RAM in place of VRAM if you physically replace the chips with bigger/better ones all you need to worry is getting compatible ones.

Comment: i have defragmented the HDD and and also made changes to the booting to use all the cores and memory to speed it up. CPU-Z is telling me that my GPU is using DDR3 2GB. Its weird.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documention of the Laptop :

https://support.hp.com/au-en/document/c03279693

According to the documentation, I think 2 x 4Go DDR3 1333Mhz (for Laptop) can do the job.

To make boot and applications faster, you should also replace the HDD by a SSD.

Comment: Well... if im gona change HDD for SSD i also need to get a new windows. Since the installation and recovery and everything is on that HDD and when i bought the laptop there was no separate DVD or CD for the OS. Im hoping that the RAM upgrade can speed it up enoguth that i can use it for another ~1 year.

Comment: You will see changes with RAM. 8Go is the minimum in 2018. SSD is a plus. And yes, changing HHD can be a pain to backup drive. You need an external drive. If you have Windows 10, no need to buy a new licence, just backup the drive and install the backup on the new one.

Comment: Personally I would just clone the HDD into a new SSD and then replace the hardware.

Comment: "Since the installation and recovery and everything is on that HDD and when i bought the laptop there was no separate DVD or CD " There should be a HP program on the PC to create HP recovery media, which can be used to restore Windows to a new hard drive, that or clone the old hard drive to the new one.